# must stop the "Spark Thrift Server" if want to use Vora Thriftserver?

Tags: vora

```
we are validating SAP HANA Vora 1.2 with IBM BigInsights now. 
When we finished install Vora, Start of Thriftserver fails with error "Could not create ServerSocket", I've found the technote http://scn.sap.com/blogs/vora/2015/12/09/sap-hana-vora--troubleshooting#11, seems it's a known issue in Vora 1.0,1.1. Did Vora 1.2 also have the same problem?
```

The differences from my log to your technote is the Port is 10002, which used by **SparkSubmit**.
    The work around is to stop "Spark Thrift Server" and then start "Vora Thriftserver".
    I guess it's a port conflict problem and seems the 10002 port is used by "Spark Thrift Server"(which is started by default in IBM BI, and create ServerSocket on the port 10002), note that there is no parameter to configure the port in Vora Thriftserver Service, the 10002 port is configured in Spark service, **modify the value of port but do not stop "Spark Thrift Server" could not resolve the issue**.
    The problem is there is no step/note said that we must stop the "Spark Thrift Server" if want to use Vora Thriftserver in SAP Vora docs, so I am not sure whether my work around is right/reasonable, Please help confirm whether Vora works like that or there is something wrong with our installation/configuration. Thanks!

Comment: Our environment:
    We used Hive in cluster and managed by Ambari,
    in Hive Configs, hive.server2.thrift.http.port = 10001,hive.server2.thrift.port=10000
    in Spark Configs, spark_thriftserver_port = 10002

Comment: The error log:
    16/07/25 02:53:41 ERROR thrift.ThriftCLIService: Error starting HiveServer2: could not start ThriftBinaryCLIService
    org.apache.thrift.transport.TTransportException: Could not create ServerSocket on address bdavm1502.svl.ibm.com/9.30.151.47:10002.
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:109)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:91)
    at org.apache.thrift.transport.TServerSocket.<init>(TServerSocket.java:87)